# SQL: Using Len() in Where clause to filter NULLS and BLANKS in one operation

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I heard this mentioned last week from a co-worker that LEN () does not parse NULL.  It does not parse to zero in a SELECT statement, however, in a WHERE statement is works, and works well. Is there any reason why one should not use Len() in where clauses to filter out Nulls and blanks ('') in one operation?

```
Drop table if exists #TestNull
Create table #TestNull (Col1 varchar(20))
Insert into #TestNull(Col1)
Values ('test'), ('1'),(Null),('')

--Len in Where statement
Select *
From #TestNull
Where Len(Col1) > 0 --ignore null and blanks

--Len in Select statement
Select Len(Col1) --Null comes back as null but blanks will return zero.
From #TestNull;
```

Comment: Yes, `Len` (and most functions) are unsargable. If you want to test just for not null, use `is not null` and if you want to test for not blank string use `!= ''`. By using the function you are forcing SQL Server to scan every row and prevent efficiently using an index.

Comment: Just do `Col1 <> ''` to ignore nulls and blank. That won't return NULL anyway. SQL uses three valued logic. The WHERE clause only returns rows where the predicate is `true` and not if `false` or `unknown` https://dbfiddle.uk/p0YAkYRd

Comment: Note that the majority of T-SQL functions return `NULL` on a `NULL` input as they're `NULL`-preserving (with the exception of things like `ISNULL` and `COALESCE` of course, and rare exceptions like `CONCAT`), `LEN` is not special in that regard.

Comment: @Stu These have the exact same execution plans and are 50/50 relative to the batch.  Not sure I follow the unsargeable perspective. 
Select *
From #TestNull
Where Len(Col1) > 0 --ignore null and blanks

Select *
From #TestNull
Where Col1<>''
and Col1 is not null;

Microsoft SQL Server 2017 (RTM-CU22) (KB4577467) - 14.0.3356.20 (X64)

Comment: You need to index `Col1` to see the difference. Range seek vs scan https://dbfiddle.uk/TBBYLr1z - in terms of actual perf difference it depends how many null or blank values you have that can be skipped by the seek

Comment: @BrennanWebb You won't see any difference on a heap or a handful of rows; the Optimizer would need to determine an index seek was the optimal data access method in the first place.

Comment: @BrennanWebb also don't read too much into the 50/50 estimate - that's based on the first-compilation only and not necessarily true for the actual execution.

Comment: Upshot of all of this is  `Col1 <> '' ` *might* use an existing index, but `len(Col1)` certainly won't ever.  Don't make a habit of it.

Comment: @MartinSmith you are quite correct.  I just tested it with 100K records.  The function call in the where makes a significant difference by forcing the query to do a full table scan, however breaking out the COL1<>'' and COL1 is not null utilized the index.  Quite interesting.

Answer (score 2):

SQL uses three valued logic.

The `WHERE` clause only returns rows where the predicate is `true` and not if `false` or `unknown`

So if you look at what `Len(Col1)` returns and what `Len(Col1) > 0` evaluates to then it should be clear why this works

```
Select Col1, 
       [Len(Col1)] = Len(Col1),
       [Len(Col1) > 0] = CASE WHEN Len(Col1) > 0 THEN 'True' WHEN NOT(Len(Col1) > 0) THEN 'False' ELSE 'Unknown' END,
       [Col1 <> ''] = CASE WHEN Col1 <> '' THEN 'True' WHEN NOT(Col1 <> '') THEN 'False' ELSE 'Unknown' END
From #TestNull
```

| Col1 | Len(Col1) | Len(Col1) > 0 | Col1 <> '' |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| test | 4 | True | True |
| 1 | 1 | True | True |
| NULL | NULL | Unknown | Unknown |
|  | 0 | False | False |

But the above table also shows that for the same reasons the simpler predicate of `Col1 <> ''` also works.

And `Col1 <> ''` is sargable (can use an index range seek).

Even in plans without an index seek using sargable expressions in favour of unsargable ones can still be beneficial in terms of more accurate cardinality estimates.

Answer (score 0):

Not a real answer, long comment, in addition to Martin Smith

If there is a business case where your table has many rows (big percentage on a big table) with null or empty values and you never gonna need to retrieve them using a filter in a where clause, you can benefit even more from [filtered indexes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/indexes/create-filtered-indexes?view=sql-server-ver16).

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX idxDataInCol1
    ON dbo.MyTable (Col1) -- INCLUDE(col2,...) 
    WHERE Col1<>'' ;
```

after writing it I just wonder about the difference with

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX idxDataInCol1
    ON dbo.MyTable (Col1) -- INCLUDE(col2,...) 
    WHERE Col1 IS NOT NULL AND Col1<>'' ;
```

Comment: There is no difference: the optimizer understands that `<>` implies `IS NOT NULL`